# Can I use public void from a class to make use of it in ArrayList to add age and name?

Tags: java, class, object, arraylist, constructor

I'm new to Java and I'm trying to get my head around constructs, classes and objects. I apologise if any of this seems stupid to you.

I have been tasked with creating an ArrayList to hold items of type Data (my class). using the .add method - I should add a certain number of names and ages then output.

I have sort of done it, but I was wondering if I could use the functions like SetAge and SetAge from my class to use within my ArrayList to create a new person and then output it together like I have with the rest. Is there another way?

Thank you for your help & explanation.

Below is my code;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class workingOn {

public static void main (String[] args)
{
    Data Fred = new Data("Fred", 21);
    Data Jo = new Data("Jo", 43);
    Data Zoe = new Data("Zoe", 37);

    ArrayList<Data> myArray = new ArrayList<Data>();

    myArray.add(Fred);
    myArray.add(Jo);
    myArray.add(Zoe);

    for (Data temp : myArray) 
    {
    System.out.println(temp.toString()); 
    }


}
}
```

Below is my class;

```
    public class Data { 

    private String name;
    private int age;

    Data(String n,int a)
    {
        name = n;
        age = a;
    }
    public String GetName()
    {
        return(name);
    }
    public void SetName(String n)
    {
        name = n;
    }
    public int GetAge()
    {
        return(age);
    }
    public void SetAge(int a)
    {
        age = a;
    }
    public void Print()
    {
        System.out.print(("("+ GetName() ));
        System.out.print(",");
        System.out.print(GetAge());
        System.out.print(") ");
    }

    //i made this so I don't output the object id
    public String toString() {
        return (name + ", " +  age);


    }
    }
```

Comment: Just to be *clear* - you want to accept *external* input (e.g. from a keyboard) and add multiple users to this list, right?

Comment: @Makoto I'm not looking to accept external input. I'm simply making up random users to a list that I'm making. Thank you for the question.

Comment: what do you mean by `Is there another way?` is it not working?

Comment: Okay - I'm not entirely sure what's wrong with what you've got, then.  You have three users which exist in this list.  Unless you're getting some kind of stack trace...I'm not convinced there's an issue...?

Comment: @Deadpool The program is working, however I was wondering if and how I can make use of the Data class functions like SetName and SetAge within my ArrayList to create a 4th person. Would it be possible?

Comment: `myArray.add(new Data("Fred", 21));` maybe?

Comment: yes exactly it is called as `Constructor` in java not function @dencn refer @Johny comment

Comment: No as in; I was wondering if you could do something along the lines myArray.SetName & myArray.SetAge ...
But thank you for the constructor, I might use it.

Comment: @dencn Your class provides a constructor. If you had an empty constructor it would be possible to invoke your setters on a "blank" instance of `Data`. But not through `myArray`. Also, your method names **should** start with a lower case letter. `setName`. `setAge`. `getName`. `getAge`.

Comment: `setName()` and `SetAge()` are the methods of `Data` class, they are used to set name,age for data object, after that you are adding that data object to arraylist right? how canyou directly access `SetName()`, `SetAge()` on arraylist directly?

Comment: So then `myArray.add(new Data()); myArray.get(myArray.size()-1).SetName("Fred");`? You will need to add a default constructor.

Comment: It makes more sense now, thank you. It's just poor knowledge of classes etc from my side and I wanted some more knowledge onto it to understand how it works. Thank you for the replies.

Answer (score 0):

Going through the comments, I am guessing you want to somehow use the setter methods (setName() and setAge()) for the class that you have designed. The easiest way would be:

```
Data d = new Data("tempName", 10);
myArray.add(d);
```

This basically creates an object of type Data and adds it to the arraylist. Let's assume that you want to change the name and age of this person you just added, then you should do this:

```
myArray.get(myArray.size() - 1).setName("newName");
myArray.get(myArray.size() - 1).setAge(18);
```

To add some explanation, when you add an object to an arraylist, it always adds in the end. We use `size()` method to get the number of objects in the Arraylist. Since index starts from 0, we use `myArray.size() - 1`. We use the `.get()` method to retrieve the object from the arraylist which takes a number as a parameter and return the object at that index.

Combining these two, we get the object at the last possible index, and call the `setName()` and `setAge()` function on it. 
Hope this helps.